# Horizontal justification/alignment of list items?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I have the following situation:

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#pricing" title="Pricing">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#booking" title="Booking">Booking</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#map" title="Map">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Since the outer container where the nav sits in is like 800px wide, the nav container is also 800px wide.

```
#access .menu ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

I'm floating all menu elements left so the align side by side. I wonder how I can create equal space between all those list items,  like this:

```
____________________________________ <- this is what I have now
item  item  item  item  item

____________________________________ <- this is what I want
item    item    item    item    item
```

Any idea how to solve this? Either with pure CSS or jQuery?

Comment: would adding this to css: ``#access .menu ul{ width: 100%; }`` do anything? or actually, ``.menu ul li { width: 100%; }`` for that matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer applies if you want it to work with any number of "li"s:

if you give your li's display:block;

```
li {float:left; display:block; }
```

then the following script does the job for your:

```
var first = $("li:first");
var allOther = $("li").not(":first, :last");
var last = $("li:last");

var remainingWidth = $(".menu").width() - first.width() - last.width();
allOther.width(remainingWidth / allOther.length).css("text-align", "center");
```

have a look at it in jsFiddler:  http://jsfiddle.net/PLQFj/14/

Answer (score 6):

### ***This Method WORK 100%!***

**CSS:**

```
.menu { position:relative; text-align:justify; text-align-last:justify; border:1px solid silver; height:2.2em; min-width:800px; }
.menu li { display:inline-block; background:silver; padding:.5em 1em; cursor:pointer; text-align:center; }
.menu li:hover { background:black; color:white; }
.menu:after { content:""; display:inline-block; width:100%; height:0; overflow:hidden; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Company</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>Menu item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this cross browser?

Answer (score 2):

```
.menu {
    text-align: justify;
}
.menu ul,
.menu li {
    display: inline;
}
.menu ul::after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    content: "";
}
```

But for cross browser compatibility (IE7), you should replace the `::after` by an additional element in the markup:

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#pricing" title="Pricing">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#booking" title="Booking">Booking</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="#map" title="Map">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</nav>
```

See [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/C5EtY/).

Answer (score 2):

***FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/QR5s3/***

****CSS (changed from floating li to inline li)****

```
#access .menu ul {
    text-align:center;   
}

#access .menu ul li:first-child {
    padding-left:0 !important;
}

#access .menu ul li:last-child {
    padding-right:0 !important;
}

#access .menu ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding:0 35px; /* ADJUST PADDING */
}
```

Comment: this is only if you have exactly four items, also hardcoding 35px for padding is not a good idea because any small change can ruin the appearance. Also :first-child is not supported by all browsers. I have proposed a jquery solution below to fix these.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#access .menu ul li 
{     
   float: left; 
   margin-right: 10px
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `margin-right` be a better choice? Otherwise the leftmost item would be incorrectly positioned.

Answer (score 0):

The first method I can think of is using a table instead of an unordered list. It would look the way you want by default. Additionally, adding more menu items would be a breeze since the alignment is automatic.

[Here's a demonstration of a couple of ways to do this](http://jsfiddle.net/BmVmB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable cross-browser non-JavaScript approach would be `<table>`'s i'm afraid. This is not very elegant, but it does the job. A float-based layout would not be capable of displaying items of variable size correctly. The whole thing should even work in IE 6.

**Markup**

```
<table class="nav">
    <tr>
        <td class="item">item</td>
        <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="item">item</td>
        <td class="separator">&nbsp;</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

The separator needs to contain a `&nbsp;`-entity to ensure that it is displayed correctly across all browsers (IE is making trouble here by ignoring empty cells).

**Style**

```
.nav, .nav tbody, .nav tr {
    width: 100%;
}
.nav .item {
    /* this forces the item to be as small as possible,
       which forces the separators to take up the
       remaining space */
    width: 1px; 
}
```

You need to make sure that the content of all items has whitespaces replaced with `&nbsp;`'s to prevent text from wrapping that would occur due to the `1px` width.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
#access
{
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    height: 50px;
    width: 800px;
}

.menu ul li
{
    float: left;
}

.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
var li = $('#access ul li').length - 1;
var w = 0;
$('#access ul li').each(function() {
    w = w + $(this).width();
});
var eachPlot = ($('#access').width() - w) / li;
$('#access ul li:gt(0)').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'margin-left': parseInt(eachPlot) + 'px'
    });
});
```